# Why does the statusBar change color after backgrounding my app?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-ios

I've got a statusBar set to `light-content` on every single screen of my app.

```
<StatusBar
  barStyle="light-content"
/>
```

For some reason, on iOS when I background and then foreground my app, the status bar suddenly becomes black (`dark-content`) any idea why this might be?

Comment: I've checked every single on of the my screens and they're all set to `light-content`. Any ideas man?

Comment: I meant a bug in react-native, not your code. Try finding an example app with the `light-content` status bar and attempt to reproduce the issue. If it works, the behavior is probably not your fault.

Comment: This is sad :( Thanks

Comment: If you are using the same statusbar color throughout your app then instead of using the StatusBar component, you can set the color directly in Xcode. Also you only need one StatusBar compontent, not one for every screen.

Comment: I'm using Exponent so no access to Xcode :( thank you though